# how to Turn off Bluetooth on wakeup from sleep

Tags: bluetooth

I am using Acer laptop with ubuntu 14.04 installed on it. Every time laptop wakeup from sleep, bluetooth gets enabled automatically. I do not want bluetooth to be enabled automatically after wakeup.

I did try the below solution.

```
sudo sed -i "s/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g" /etc/xdg/autostart/*.desktop
```

Then Open Dash And Search For "Startup Applications". Find Bluetooth In The List And Uncheck it. Click Close On The Side.

However, when I open startup application, I do not see bluetooth in the list.

Please suggest..

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug report about it;
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1298552

As you can see from the report status, bug has been expired, importance is low and not assigned to anyone. I highly believe that the bug will not be resolved if no one reports a crash about it.

**Workaround:**

You may try disabling bluetooth service by writing a script on wake-up process. pm-utils provides a script based controlling mechanism. You can find the examples under `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/`directory.

Create a new script called 99buetooth_disable;

```
$ sudo touch /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99buetooth_disable
```

Open it up with your favorite editor (mine is nano btw);

```
$ sudo nano /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99buetooth_disable
```

Put those commands into it;

```
#!/bin/sh

case "$1" in
    resume)
        echo "Disabling bluetooth..."
        sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth stop
esac
```

Additionally you can also start and restart the service with following commands if you want;

```
sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth start
sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart
```

Now bluetooth service should be stopped after a clean resume.